# Condition in dataframe pandas (NaN columns ) and condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to count the length of time a server is stopped from a dataset. 
I know the downtime but not the duration.

I have this df:

```py
index                   a          b     c     reboot   stop
2018-06-25 12:49:00    NaN        NaN   NaN     0         1
2018-06-25 12:50:00    NaN        NaN   NaN     0         1
2018-06-25 12:51:00    NaN        NaN   NaN     1         1
2018-06-25 12:52:00    NaN        NaN   NaN     0         1
2018-06-25 12:53:00    NaN        NaN   NaN     0         1
2018-06-25 12:54:00    NaN        NaN   NaN     0         1
2018-06-25 12:55:00    NaN        NaN   NaN     0         1
2018-06-25 12:56:00    NaN        NaN   1.2      0         0
2018-06-25 12:57:00    NaN        NaN   NaN     0         1
2018-06-25 12:58:00    NaN        NaN   NaN     1         1
2018-06-25 12:59:00    NaN        NaN   NaN     0         1
2018-06-25 13:00:00    NaN        NaN   NaN     0         1
2018-06-25 13:01:00    NaN        NaN   NaN     0         0
```

If `a, b, c = NaN`,
my server stops when `reboot, stop = 1`
and starts when `reboot, stop = 0`.

Desired output:

```py
index                        period
2018-06-25 12:51:00             5
2018-06-25 12:58:00             3
```

Comment: `df[df.reboot.eq(1)]` ?

Comment: please elaborate on what you're looking for.  this statement -- 

`if a,b,c = nan stop =1 my server stop inreboot =1 and stop = 1 and start inreboot =0 and stop =0`  -- makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will accomplish what you want:

```
# Create a new column which identifies stopped times
df['stopped'] = np.nan
idx_stopped = (pd.isnull(df.a)) & (pd.isnull(df.b)) & (pd.isnull(df.c)) & (df.reboot == 1) & (df.stop == 1)
df.loc[idx_stopped, 'stopped'] = 1
df.loc[(df.reboot == 0) & (df.stop == 0), 'stopped'] = 0
df.stopped = df.stopped.ffill()
df.stopped = df.stopped.fillna(0)
df.loc[df.stopped == 0, 'stopped'] = np.nan

# Count the number of periods for each stop instance
v = df.stopped[::-1]
cumsum = v.cumsum().fillna(method='pad')
reset = -cumsum[v.isnull()].diff().fillna(cumsum)
result = v.where(v.notnull(), reset).cumsum()
df['period'] = result[::-1]

# Identify the time each stop incident began
df['first'] = (df.stopped == 1) & (pd.isnull(df.stopped.shift(1)))
df2 = df[['index', 'period']][df['first']]
df2.period = df2.period.astype(int)

print(df2)
```

```
                 index  period
2  2018-06-25 12:51:00       5
9  2018-06-25 12:58:00       3
```